# how to order 2 SQL Fields in asc and desc dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I want to Order a SQL Select Query where there's 2 fields that are in the order by. I then need to decide if one is Descending and the other as Ascending. How is this done

I want something like:

```
Select * from Customer
Order By Date @asc_or_Desc_date, Name @asc_or_Desc_name
```

Anyone got any ideas?

I have tried this but it seems to fail

```
SELECT 

    Customer_ID,                        
    Name,                               
    Age                                         

FROM #Customer
ORDER BY 

    CASE WHEN @fieldSort ='Name'
        THEN ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Name) * 
            case when @directionOfSort = 'A' 
                THEN 1 ELSE -1 END,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Age) * 
            case when @directionOfSort = 'A' 
                THEN 1 ELSE -1 END,
        END
```

Anyone know how to sort this?

Comment: If you are going to add more details to your question, please try to do it in such a way that our answers didn't become irrelevant because of that. If you see that probable, better post a new question, possibly with reference to this one, if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to create your SQL statement dynamically in order to use a variable:

```
DECLARE @asc_desc VARCHAR(4);

SET @asc_desc = 'DESC';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000);

SET @sql = 'Select * from Customer Order By Date ' + @asc_desc + ', Name';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

This will order Date `DESCENDING` and Name `ASCENDING`.

You only need to add `DESC` if you want to use `DESCENDING` as `ASCENDING` is default.

Comment: `sp_execute` needs `EXEC` before it in this case.

Comment: @Andriy M: Yeah, I was trying to run the code in SSMS as well as correct the question.

Comment: NOTE: Be very aware of SQL Injection when doing this.  The parameters need to be supplied by your own code, and/or the values need validating.  If you make this inside a stored procedure, check them inside the stored procedure, just to be sure.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT 
  Customer_ID,                        
  Name,                               
  Age                                         
FROM
  #Customer
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN @field = 'Name' AND @direction = 'A' THEN Name ELSE NULL END ASC,
  CASE WHEN @field = 'Name' AND @direction = 'D' THEN Name ELSE NULL END DESC,
  CASE WHEN @field = 'Age'  AND @direction = 'A' THEN Age  ELSE NULL END ASC,
  CASE WHEN @field = 'Age'  AND @direction = 'D' THEN Age  ELSE NULL END DESC
```

I wouldn't want to do that over many different combinations though.  If you have a lot of combinations I'd do somethign based on the following...

```
SELECT 
  Customer_ID,                        
  Name,                               
  Age                                         
FROM
(
  SELECT
    Customer_ID,
    Name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name) AS "name_order",
    Age,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Age)  AS "age_order"
  FROM
    #Customer
)
  AS [data]
ORDER BY 
  CASE @field1
    WHEN 'Name' THEN CASE @direction1 WHEN 'A' THEN name_order ELSE -name_order END
    WHEN 'Age'  THEN CASE @direction1 WHEN 'A' THEN age_order  ELSE -age_order  END
    ELSE NULL
  END,
  CASE @field2
    WHEN 'Name' THEN CASE @direction2 WHEN 'A' THEN name_order ELSE -name_order END
    WHEN 'Age'  THEN CASE @direction2 WHEN 'A' THEN age_order  ELSE -age_order  END
    ELSE NULL
  END
```

Repeat as many times as is required...

**Note**: Just because it can be done this way, doesn't mean it should be done this way.

Comment: +1 for the first one, even if it's more cumbersome, because the second one only orders by one column whereas it seems like the OP wants it to be by two.

Comment: The question syas Name <or> Age, and Asc <or> Desc?  Though I may just be being blind, it's not uncommon...

Comment: Same logic, but slightly refactored, to make it obvious how to extend to mutiple orders.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2005+ you could employ the following device:

```
WITH CustomerCTE AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    DateSort = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date),
    NameSort = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name)
  FROM Customer
)
SELECT *
FROM CustomerCTE
ORDER BY DateSort * @DateSortDir, NameSort * @NameSortDir
```

The vars in this case should be either `1` or `-1`.

---

**EDIT**

The additionally posted example seems to imply that the order of columns to use in ORDER BY should be dynamical too. And it also now seems that the order direction is specified uniformly for both columns.

Whether it is so or not (the question has become a bit more ambiguous), both are assumed in my second solution.

```
DECLARE @IntSortDir int;
SET @IntSortDir = CASE @directionOfSort WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END;

WITH CustomerCTE AS (
  SELECT
    Customer_ID,
    Name,
    Age,
    NameSort = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name),
    AgeSort  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date)
  FROM Customer
)
SELECT
  Customer_ID,
  Name,
  Age
FROM CustomerCTE
ORDER BY
  CASE @fieldSort WHEN 'Age' THEN AgeSort END * @IntSortDir,
  NameSort * @directionOfSort,
  CASE @fieldSort WHEN 'Name' THEN AgeSort END * @IntSortDir
```

`@fieldSort` specifies the primary order column. The other one automatically becomes the secondary one.

Comment: SELECT 

 EXT_Design_Standard_ID      
 Standards_Name        
 Ref           

FROM #LastUpdateTemp --ORDER BY Date_Changed DESC

ORDER BY 
 
 CASE WHEN @fieldSort ='Standards Name'
  THEN ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Standards_Name) * 
   case when @directionOfSort = 'A' 
    THEN 1 ELSE -1 END,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Ref) * 
   case when @directionOfSort = 'A' 
    THEN 1 ELSE -1 END,
  END,

Comment: problem with mines it fails, any idea how to sort it?

Comment: You mean, you want not only the direction of ordering be dynamical, but the order of `ORDER BY` columns too?

Comment: I managed to the first part of the sort to work but when it comes to so

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is the solution

Explanation:
1. Ordering the row number on the basis of SQL input param  order by (DESC, ASC)
2. Againt ordering the row number in outer query

Try this code (working)

DECLARE @PageNum int
DECLARE @PageSize int
DECLARE @TotalRowsNum int
DECLARE @SortColumn varchar(200)
DECLARE @SortOrder varchar(5)

SET @PageNum = 4;
SET @PageSize = 10;
SET @SortColumn = 'CODE_ID';
SET @SortOrder = 'DESC';

WITH QueryResult AS
(

SELECT *,
CASE @SortOrder WHEN 'ASC' THEN
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @SortColumn ASC) 
ELSE
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @SortColumn DESC) 
END AS 'RowNumber'

FROM TABLE_NAME 
) 
SELECT * FROM QueryResult
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN (@PageNum - 1) * @PageSize + 1 AND @PageNum * @PageSize
ORDER BY RowNumber ASC
```