# MySQL ORDER BY depending on CASE order ASC or DESC

Tags: mysql, case

I want based on a value queried from another table order ASC or DESC.

So something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY 
    CASE (SELECT sorting from table2 WHERE table2.id = ?)
        WHEN 1 THEN table.date ASC END 
        WHEN 0 THEN table.date DESC END
    END
```

Is anything like that available in MySQL?

I've seen for MS-SQL Server some solution: [how to order 2 SQL Fields in asc and desc dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993229/how-to-order-2-sql-fields-in-asc-and-desc-dynamically)

**EDIT**: I just saw I made a mistake in the description, fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
order by if((select sorting from table2 where table2.id = ?) = 1,
  unix_timestamp(table.date), -unix_timestamp(table.date))
```

negation works if your column is numeric. if it's a string, you might be able to find another function to map high values to low values...

Comment: this is not correct at all. the guy want to sort a different tabel by different field. As seen from the questions the values of the field sorting are 0 or 1 only, so ordering by sorting or -sorting is useless

Comment: No, the values of the field are actually *date* values, not 0 or 1, so this technique could be useful. +1 for a creative, out-of-the-box alternative.

Comment: @NedretRecep You read it wrong, sorting from table2 can only be 0 or 1, sorting from table is different

Comment: @xception, exactly. So how the provided answer works correctly. So we have 'table2' with a field 'sorting' that is 0 or 1. Then based on a value of this field another table named 'table' with a field of type date named 'date' is being sorted ascending or descending. And the given answer (which I now see is accepted as working strangly) is not correct as it never sets anywhere the sorting by the field 'table.date'

Comment: @NedretRecep With all due respect, you're actually the one not interpreting the question correctly. The intent is not to sort on the 0/1 value, but for the 0/1 value from the first table to drive the ascending/descending direction of the sort in the *second* table. That's exactly what the accepted solution does. Think you're just not quite interpreting it correctly.

Comment: @exception, now with the newest version, it is correct. The version of the answer I was objecting is (and this was the actual version when I commented)

order by if((select sorting from table2 where table2.id = ?) = 1,
  sorting, -sorting)

which obviously is not using at all the field table.date.

Answer (score 2):

T-SQL statements can't be constructed conditionally in the manner your suggesting.

You need to construct your query into a varchar, then perform an EXEC against the constructed string, along the lines of the following:

```
Declare @QueryString varchar(100)
Declare @Direction int

Select @direction = sorting
  from table2
 where table2.id=? //from your original, not clear how you are providing it

Set @QueryString = 'Select * from table order by yourField ' + case when @direction=1 then 'ASC' else 'DESC' end

Exec (@QueryString)
```

---

**EDIT** Presuming your order_by field is numeric, one trick you employ (although I'm not sure it would fall into the "best practices" camp) would be to multiply the value of the order by field by -1 to reverse the default order, eg

```
Select @Direction = sorting
  from table2
 where table2.id=? 

Select * 
  from table
  order by (case when @direction=1 then -1 else 1 end) *yourField
```

Comment: It's not Microsoft to be using t-sql

Comment: Blast. Misread the OP's post to think he needed a T-SQL solution.